# Created a new app on Bluemix and unable to Add GIT

Tags: node.js, git, ibm-cloud

I just created a new Node.JS web app on Bluemix and when I click on the ADD GIT button on the overview page I get the following error:

> "Bad Request
>   Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>   Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
>   Cookie"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clear your browser cache and retry it should work. Otherwise restart browser and try again.

I had the same issue yesterday and restarting browser worked.